Hide Dashboard and Profile from non admin in sidebar
I want the Dashboard and Profile tabs to be hidden from users who are not administrators in Wordpress. Specifically, I created a user group order_manager and I want it to have access to orders only, I was able to hide all the items using the functions I found, the only thing left is Dashboard and Profile.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
